# Bottom align view to background image where background image is taking half screen width using xcode autolayout

Tags: ios8, autolayout, swift2, xcode7

I am trying show a view at the bottom of background image, and that backgorund image is taking half of the screen. In sotryboard it looks fine but in in emulators it is not showing view at the bottom of image.

**here are my layout constraints** 
[image]

**Below is result in emulators**
[image]

In emulators view is not bottom aligned with the image. I am new to xcode. what am i doing wrong? Image size is fixed to 1000x1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint seems right, check the Clip Subviews of the background imageView on storyboard should fix this.

[image]